# Source syntax error in SQL query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trying to use this query in MySQL Workbench. The SOURCE line gets a syntax error, I've been doing research to figure out why with no success. Any ideas?

```
drop database commonfx;
create database commonfx character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
use commonfx;
SET autocommit = 0;
SOURCE 'C:\Users\MK\Downloads\testdb.sql';
commit;
SET autocommit = 1;
```

Error:

> Syntax error, unexpected SOURCE_SYM

Comment: Execute it with the `--verbose` option, e.g. `mysql --verbose < text_file` and paste the results, along with the contents of c:\users\mk\downloads\testdb.sql.

Comment: I don't think the contents of the file are relevant, it's complaining that the `SOURCE` command itself is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench doesn't support the SOURCE command (yet). Instead paste-in the content of your file instead for now.

Comment: Unfortunately file is 700mb, so that's not an option

Comment: 700MB? That's certainly a generated file, not something generally useful. Use the restore function in MySQL Workbench Admin then.